# Rails3 to separate apps or not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

I'm quite new at Rails but can find my way around for the time being.

We are working on moving our old legacy PHP app to rails3. There is a Management system which handles transactions/contact/reports. Then a few extra 'modules' such as: Campaigns, Events, etc.

Should we create three separate rails apps and connect them via ActiveResource?  If not, what else should we be looking at.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only ever need one app. If you need many databases ( which I highly doubt you do ) , then you can have one app handle many databases. But again, you probably only need one database, and you're definately alright with one app.